# Can't get "If paused" to work in videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm trying to show an overlay on my video when the video is paused. 
Now from the docs I took:

```
var isPaused = myPlayer.paused();
var isPlaying = !myPlayer.paused();
```

And implemented it as follows:

```
var isPaused = myPlayer.paused();
if (isPaused == true) {
$("#social_share").fadeIn(1500);
}

var isPlaying = !myPlayer.paused();
if (isPlaying == true) {
$("#social_share").fadeOut(1500); 
}
```

Unfortunately this did not work, and I can't find why. 
Any thoughts are highly apricaited!

(PS: It shows on initial start which would be logical since the player is paused at that time. Any idea's on how to could be prevented would also be more then welcome.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for events. Specifically, the `pause` and `play` events.

Try:

```
myPlayer.on("pause", function () {
    $("#social_share").fadeIn(1500);
});

myPlayer.on("play", function () {
    $("#social_share").fadeOut(1500);
});
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#events

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks a ton! now I know how to implement the events :)

Comment: Why does the events list here not show 'pause' and 'play'? https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html - it just shows events like 'ended'

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I'm honestly not sure! A lot has probably changed with this library since 2013 (when I posted this answer). I've been looking through their latest docs (like what you posted), and I really can't find anything about what events are actually supported, I'm sorry